# I need help connecting 2 solar panels in paralel

Tags: solar-cell, panel

I'm new to Electronics but I love solar panels and hiking.

So, I bought 2 of [these](https://www.tomtop.com/p-l1613.html) and one of [these](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Dual-USB-Solar-Boost-DC-DC-3V-step-up-to-5V-3A-Power-Supply-Charger-for-Iphone/250859839731?epid=15006766991&hash=item3a686960f3:g:ab4AAMXQU6tQ9orA)
and I connected them.

I cut 2 USB Cables, connected + with + and - with - from each Cable and connected it to the DC-DC booster. The amperage is not doubled and the output Volts are lower than 5V which should be the constant output of the booster. The panels were solar oriented and the output was only 0.02 A with Bright enough sun from those 2 solar panels. The panels separately work fine, it is only when I connect them to the booster that they act weird.

And this is roughly the scheme I'm using, except solar panel specifications and MPPT:
[Charging Powerbank with Solar Panels better with converter or mmpt or without?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325110/charging-powerbank-with-solar-panels-better-with-converter-or-mmpt-or-without?rq=1)

Is the problem in booster or is it me doing something wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: How did you measure the current?

Comment: I used a multimeter/USB chargerDoctor on the output of the USB controller/booster/DC-DC.

Comment: And this is roughly the scheme I'm using, except solar panel specifications and MPPT:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325110/charging-powerbank-with-solar-panels-better-with-converter-or-mmpt-or-without?rq=1

Comment: So if you have two solar panels in parallel, the voltage will be reduced to the voltage of the worst panel. But lets say there is a lot of sun and you have 6V over the panel.
What do you think the boost converter which boosts voltages from 2.5-5V to 5V will do when there is 6V on its input. You may want to check out the differences between Boost, Buck, Buck-boost converters.

Comment: The input to the booster cannot be 6V because the output of the panels is max 5V. But why when there was a lot of sun the booster was not outputting the voltage of the worst (which in good sun should be something around 4.5-5V) and the total current of the 2 panels? And if it is called a booster why isn't the output current 5V even if the input comes from worst panel? It should boost the current, right?

Comment: Too many technical errors in comments. A PV is a current source below Voc , measure short circuit current and open circuit voltage of each then in tandem  and compute Voc/Isc for all in question Please . Then disclose link specs for MPPT actual design and layout. You need a buck-boost MPPT

Comment: First off, this solar panels that you linked give these specifications in the description: Solar panel output: 6.8V 1700mA. Second a boost converter, converts lower voltages to higher ones: E.G. 2.5V 1A becomes 5V 500mA (With a 100% efficient conversion). This means that the boost converter you have is build to boost voltages of (2.5V-5V) to 5V outputs. The 5V outputs are needed for USB devices, however according to your solar panel specs the input op the DCDC can get higher as 5V. Which the boost converter doesnt like.

Comment: A voltage boost drains more current than your supply is the problem , so its output fails. You would get better results with no MPPT

Comment: In the Solar Panel Specifications it is also written: USB output: 5V 1200mA, so I assume that the panel can't output more than 5V which why I decided to by a booster, a step-up DC-DC converter and it is also why I thought it would work and I still Think it should.

Comment: As long as PV’s have reverse V protection (USB bat > V pv

Comment: Tony Stewart, I really appreciate your input but I am so new Electronics and stuff, this is why I need help, not only terminology and fancy Word, I need a bit of explanation.
I Think of it this way: 2 panels with the same max output V connected together in paralel to a USB converter/V regulator to stabilise the voltage and double the current. And what I Think or at least what I read a booster does is when there is not enough sun and the current is low then the booster maximises it to stable 5V output. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: OK, what do you guys think I should to make it work?

Comment: @aninteresteduser: electronics is a very complex subject indeed and terminology and fancy words are necessary. If you love hiking and want solar pannels, just buy a commercial product. But if you want to build something by yourself, you'll have to understand terminology and fancy word. Electronics is not like Lego.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I didn't mean to offend anyone. But I mentioned that I am inexperienced and I need just a bit of help and explanation of what is wrong with what I want to do. I thought this is why this Community is for. I could read and read and study but then I would know everything and didn't need to post questions here. Anyway, I really what to know what is it that it is not working with the system I'm using and why. And maybe what to do to make it work.

Comment: https://www.banggood.com/MPPT-Solar-Panel-Controller-5A-DC-DC-Step-down-CCCV-Charging-Module-Display-LED-p-1089155.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN

will this thing do the work even if the panels are rated at 5V max USB output?

Comment: The Solar panel description implies it has a Buck regulator on it's output; the panel produces 6.8V and the USB cable provides 5V. So your additional DC-DC convertor (which is a Boost) does nothing. The DC-DC you are using uses voltage in the 2.5- 5V input range, but it is poorly specified ...at one point saying the input can be 2.5 - 45V (which would require a Buck/Boost circuit). IMO you need access to the actual solar panel output for your application, then you can use diodes to combine the two solar panels and a Buck converter to regulate the output.

Comment: Thank you very much, you clarified the situation for me. But, when the output from the panel is not 5V but less, shouldn't the DC-DC take it and boost to a 5V output? I mean the panel will never give a 5V constant voltage because of the flexibility of the sun. So, when the sun is not so bright and the voltage lower than 5V, the DC-DC should provide a constant 5V output and I assume (again, correct me if I'm wrong) if I attach as many panels that have max output 5V and all of them connected in paralel and with slightly different voltage at any particular moment, shouldn't the booster output...

Comment: ...a constant 5V and a sum of current(Amps)? Thank you!

Comment: @JackCreasey I suspect they simply missed the dot in 4.5V. Not a big difference, right? ;)

Comment: @Maple You might be right ….in which case 5V is overvoltage input. Either way I don't think that DC-DC is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your panel specification:

Solar panel output: 6.8V 1700mA
USB output: 5V 1200mA
USB version: 2.1

This means that not only the panel has **voltage regulator inside**, but most likely some kind of support for USB battery charging specification. Connecting these in parallel is not a good idea.

So, check your panels - do you have direct access to 6.8V mentioned in spec? If you do, then that is where you have to tap in and that output you can connect in parallel to get theoretical (highly unbelievable, though) 6.8V 3.4A

If you don't have access to 6.8V then next thing to do is measure actual USB output voltage on a single panel. If it abruptly drops from around 4.5~5V down to 0 in low sun then the chip inside is too smart for your application, no kind of booster will help you here. You need different solar panels with unregulated outputs to connect them in parallel. These panels usually generate over 6V in bright sun.

Now, as mentioned in many comments, you need to understand the difference between DC-DC converters. Booster modules *boost* voltage, while at the same time *reduce* current. They are not happy if you put more than something like Voutput - 1.0V on their input.

When solar panel output can change from say, 3V to 6V, the output voltage 5V fits right in the middle of it. Which means you need "Buck-Boost" module, the one that can boost when input below and buck when input above the output.

As a side note, your reference to the *unanswered* question riddled with conceptual errors and links to questionable components underscores the lack of understanding. I applaud your willingness to learn this stuff. I don't believe anybody will be able to help you much until you do learn the basics.

Here are some connection options for you. In the first you need to figure out your own wiring, but you'd keep an option to use USB output of a single panel, if necessary. In the second you can use USB cables that you already have, but you might accidentally damage USB device if you plug it directly into panel.

[image]

Comment: Great, I'm on the right track. Thank you very very much. Everytime I used the panel it never showed more than 5V so assume it is a max 5V solar panel and yes it drops and ups the Voltage with the suns brightness. Can you please explain a bit this part: They are not happy if you put more than something like Voutput - 1.0V on their input. What will happen if I remove the booster and connect them in paralel with only the Cables? and what if I remove the panels' voltage regulator and connect it directly to a buck-boost module? thank you!

Comment: 1) Boost modules work when input is below output. e.g. 4V in, 5V out. 2) if you remove booster and connect USB outputs in parallel you would either have 5V at double current, or you would have **unstable** 5V, depending on internal regulator schematics. 3) if you remove internal regulator and connect panel directly to buck-boost module you will have stable 5V as long as sun is bright enough. ...or you accidentally damage you panel beyond repair while removing that regulator.

Comment: I don't know the basics and you helped me a lot and engaged me in looking deeper into these issues I'm experiencing...;)..one last question, if in low light the panel for example outputs a 3.6 V and sends it to the module, why isn't the module boosting it up to 5V? the input is below input. thanks

Comment: Assuming your wiring is correct if panel outputs 3.6V the boost module _should_ output 5V. If it doesn't there are several possibilities: 1) the panel does not output 3.6V you think it does. It's internal circuit might cut off the output to comply with USB spec. 2) If USB output in the panel really supports USB protocol as description suggests then it expects actual USB device to be connected, not some DC-DC. It might not supply enough power without it. 3) most DC-DC modules require minimal load present for normal operation. Your module might need that load. 3) your module might be defective.